# Keras max_pool3d got an expected keyword argument 'data_format'

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer, max-pooling

I am running a workshop with students using Keras, and all of the students have the same anaconda3 installation in windows.

The following code is giving an error for most of the students except 2 of them:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm

from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Lambda, Layer, Conv3D, MaxPooling3D, Flatten, UpSampling3D, Reshape
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K
from keras import metrics
#from keras.datasets import mnist

batch_size = 100
original_dim = 32000 #dimX x dimY x dimZ
latent_dim = 2
intermediate_dim = 512 #256
epochs = 5
epsilon_std = 1.0

x = Input(shape=(40, 20, 40, 1))
h = Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
h = MaxPooling3D((2, 2, 2), padding='same')(h)

>>max_pool3d() got an expected keyword argument 'data_format'
```

In the [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/pooling/#maxpooling3d), you can see that the function `maxpooling3d()` takes other optional parameters like precisely `data_format`, but since we are not even specifying it, why are we getting this error? And why is it not consistent through all installations?

Comment: Is the keras version same in all machines?

Comment: You should include the full stack trace in the question.

Comment: Thank you @VivekKalyanarangan for the hint, we realized there were different versions among the participants and only those with the oldest version had it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be better if you include the full stacktrace to be sure, but it looks like you're using tensorflow backend and the problem is with **tensorflow version**.

Keras `MaxPooling3D` layer invokes `tf.nn.max_pool3d` function, which in [v0.12](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/nn/pooling#max_pool3d) didn't have a `data_format` argument. In the [latest versions](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/max_pool3d), it has one, that's why keras expects it.

Try to upgrade tensorflow on all machines.

Comment: Yes, it was a version problem, thanks for the lead. We found it easier to downgrade Keras instead of upgrading Tensorflow for the time being, but it worked.